# Meteor.Js Sorting results from a collection is resulting in unexpected token

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

This is my code to get all the documents from the products collection and my collection has a field called name and I would like to arrange the results alphabetically

```
 Template.products.helpers({products:
      products.find({},{sort:{name:1}});
    });
```

Comment: and the question is .... ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the syntax error - in the 2nd line remove final ";".

And as advice - I think it's better to make it a function.

```
Template.products.helpers({
    products: function () {
        return products.find({}, {sort: {name: 1}})
    }
});
```

ES2015 style

```
Template.products.helpers({
    products: () => products.find({}, {sort: {name: 1}})
});
```